# how to create a grid view with only ONE image from nodes containing multiple images?

Tags: 6, views, media

I have Nodes that have an Image field that can have any number of Image Fields. I want to create a Grid View in which I should only a single IMage field (can be the first one or any one actually).

Attached image shows my Views settings that shows multiple images - how do I limit to picking a single image from each node for the grid views display?

(I am in DRUPAL 6)

[image: Views Screen Display for Grid View]

Comment: tick the answer if you solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily, by clicking the **"Image Field"** and check the **Group Multiple Values** and set **show values** as **1** and set **starting from** 0

see the image below

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bala that worked - I have marked your response as the answer.